# how to reproject an image programatically in c# using gdal

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr, gdalwarp

I have to reproject an image programmatically in c# using gdal library.
For the moment i'm a little bit lost in gdal and i don't really now which methods i have to use.
I think i will have to calculate tie points, set reference systems and then reproject but i don't now how to manage this.

Can somebody help me with exemples or tutorials?

Best regards,
Christophe.

Comment: Not an answer but the workflow should be quite similar C/C++ methods found in http://www.gdal.org/warptut.html (provided ofc that the C# binding are complete - they should )